# Does a rail-to-rail input fully-differential amplifier need Common mode feedback at Output nodes?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, common-mode, rail-to-rail

I am designing an Op-amp with rail-to-rail inputs and the operation being fully differential in nature. I am trying to understand whether I will still need a CMFB (common-mode feedback) circuit to fix the output nodes to a certain voltage as done generally? I had a perception that I might not need it given the changing ICMR, which should change the natural output node voltages. I am not very clear about it; looking for some inputs on this.

TIA

Comment: Are you designing an actual opamp or a circuit that uses an opamp?

Comment: Designing a full rail-to-rail op-amp from scratch, along with the required peripheral circuit.